# Docker placement preference vs Docker placement constraints

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am learning Docker. As part of my learning there is one topic I haven't understood. The usage of the Docker placement preferences when compared with constraints in Docker.

I have been keep searching in internet and asked many people everyone aware of the constraints not the preferences. I haven't found any good reference in internet. What is the use of placement preferences in Docker? When should I use them? Any sample example?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-placement-preferences---placement-pref

Comment: i have gone through this documentation but i don't see good example or usecase for preferences

Answer (score 10):

Placement prefs allow you to `spread` your replicas across nodes with certain tags, choosing to put the replicas as much `diverse` as possible.

Constraints will constrain (limit) the replicas to those nodes that match the constraint.

Imagine you have 4 servers in 2 datacenters (east, west) and some of the servers have an SSD drive, while others don't.

If you apply the following labels to the nodes:

```
node-1: datacenter=us-east, disk=ssd
node-2: datacenter=us-east, disk=ssd
node-3: datacenter=us-west, disk=sas
node-4: datacenter=us-west, disk=nl-sas
```

If you would deploy a service with 2 replicas and you want to provide geographic redundancy, you would start that service as follows:

```
docker service create \
  --replicas 2 \
  --name webserver \
  --placement-pref 'spread=node.labels.datacenter' \
  mywebservice:production
```

Docker Swarm would then try to "spread" the 2 replicas across both datacenters, so you'll end up with 1 replica on either node-1 or node-2, and the other replica on node-3 or node-4.

If you have a service (eg a reporting job) that does a lot of IOPS, you'll probably want to use your SSD equipped servers, so you'll place a constraint on the service:

```
docker service create \
  --constraint 'node.labels.disk == ssd' \
  myreporter:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to "Control service placement" section in https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/

In short 
Placement constraint ***limits where a task can run*** (a task will not run on a node unless it satisfies the constraint, it will remain in pending state)

While placement constraints limit the nodes a service can run on, placement preferences ***try to place tasks on appropriate nodes in an algorithmic way*** (currently, only spread evenly). Placement preference helps you in distributing the tasks based on a constraint across the nodes.

e.g.
placement constraint of node.region=east will let a task only run on nodes labelled "east"
whereas,
placement preference of node.region=east will help you spread the tasks across nodes evenly based node.region. If any node does not have this label, it will still get the task.